# Intel ICX compiler list of optimization flags

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, icx

In the gcc compiler I can specify the arguments `-Q --help=optimizers` to get a list of the enabled/disabled optimization flags at the current `O` level. Is there a similar command for the intel icx compiler? If not, is there a resource that lists the optimization flags by O0, O1, O2, and O3?

I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: @wallyk that link's seems to link to a non existent page :/

Comment: That's weird. It should be this:  https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-dpcpp-cpp-compiler-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compilation.html

Answer (score 3):

Please visit the link below which has the list of optimization flags and their significance which may help you.

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/optimization-options/o.html

Besides this, to get list of optimization flags:

1. `-fsave-optimization-record= "format"` Generates an optimization record file in a specific format.
2. `-fsave-optimization-record` Generates a YAML optimization record file.
   In addition, you can try `"icx --help | grep optimization"` and check for the option which suits best for your purpose

Comment: Link changed. Go here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options.html  and click 'Optimization options' on the left menu.

Comment: Also, I believe `fsave-optimization-record` was implemented in clang and later very partially in gcc - but never in intel. And it never gave a list of optimization flags, for any compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The link above is for the new non-Clang-based Intel compiler icc (they refer to it as classic).
To get compiler options for icx, have a look here:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-dpcpp-cpp-compiler-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/alphabetical-list-of-compiler-options.html